# Regex to text before set of numbers

Tags: c#, regex

I have text like this

Inc12345_Month
Ted12345_Month
J8T12345_Month

What I need to do is extract the 12345 and also remove everything before it. This will be done in C#

`.+?(?=\d_Monthly)` was working in a regex tester online but when I put it in my code it only returned 5_Month.

Edit: the 12345 could be a variable length so I cannot [0-9] multiple times.

Edit2: Code this was just to try and remove everything before the 12345

```
string text = /* the above text pulled in from a file */;
Regex reg = new Regex(@".+?(?=\d+_Monthly)");
text = reg.Replace(string, "");
```

Comment: `when I put it in my code it only returned 5_Month`  Obvious question: Where is your code?

Comment: Regex is very different between the platforms. C#, Javascript, Java.

Comment: Why you cannot use simply `(\d+)_Month`?

Comment: Why can't you just use `\d+` to get the number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this function to strip it:

```
private static Regex getNumberAndBeyondRegex = new Regex(^.{2}\D+(\d.*)$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
public static string GetNumberAndBeyond(string input)
{
    var match = getNumberAndBeyondRegex.Match(input);
    if (!match.Success) throw new ArgumentException("String isn't in the correct format.", "input");
    return match.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

The regex at work is `^.{2}\D+(\d.*)$`

It works by grabbing anything that's a number, after at least one character that isn't a number. It'll not only match `_Month` but also other endings.

The regex exists out of a few parts:

1. `^` matches the beginning of the string
2. `.{2}` matches any two characters, to prevent a digit from matching if it's the first or 2nd character, you can increase this number to be equal to the minimum prefix length - 1
3. `\D+` matches at least one character that isn't a number
4. `(` starts capturing a group
5. `\d.*` matches at least one number and any values beyond that
6. `)` closes the capturing group
7. `$` matches the end of the string

There are a lot of different regex flavors, many of them have slight differences in terms of escaping, capturing, replacing and quite surely some others.

For testing .NET regexes online I use the free version of the tool [RegexHero](http://regexhero.net/tester/), it has an popup every now and then, but it makes up for that time by showing you live results, capture groups, and instant replacing. Next to having quite a lot of features.

If you want to match anywhere within the string, you can use the regex `\d+_Month`, it is very similiar to your original regex. In code:

```
new Regex("\d+_Month").Match(input).Value
```

**Edit:**
Based on the format you supplied in the comment I've created a regex and function to parse the entire file name:

```
private static Regex parseFileNameRegex = new Regex(@"^.*\D(\d+)_Month_([a-zA-Z]+)\.(\w+)$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
public static bool TryParseFileName(string fileName, out int id, out string month, out string fileExtension)
{
    id = 0; month = null; fileExtension = null;
    if (fileName == null) return false;
    var match = parseFileNameRegex.Match(fileName);
    if (!match.Success) return false;
    if (!int.TryParse(match.Groups[1].Value, out id) || id < 1) return false; // Convert the ID into a number
    month = match.Groups[2].Value;
    fileExtension = match.Groups[3].Value;
    return true;
}
```

In the parse function it requires the ID to be at least 1, 0 isn't accepted (and negative numbers won't match the regex), if you don't want this restriction, simply remove `|| id < 1` from the function.

Using the function would look like:

```
int id; string month, fileExtension;
if (!TryParseFileName("CompanyName_ClientName12345_Month_Nov.pdf", out id, out month, out fileExtension))
    throw new FormatException("File name is incorrectly formatted."); // Do whatever you want when you get an invalid filename
// Use id, month and fileExtension here :)
```

The regex `^.*\D(\d+)_Month_([a-zA-Z]+)\.(\w+)$` works like:

1. `^` matches the beginning of the string
2. `.*\D` matches at least one non-numeric character
3. `(\d+)` captures at least 1 number, this is the ID
4. `_Month_` is the literal text in between
5. `([a-zA-Z]+)` matches and captures at least 1 letter, this is the month
6. `\.` matches a . character
7. `(\w+)` matches and captures any alphanumeric (letters and numbers), this is the file extension
8. `$` matches the end of the string

Comment: I'm getting 8T12345_Monthly with your above code on J8T12345_Monthly.

Comment: That's correct, I'll be changing the code to require at least 2 characters after the start. However, cases like these will make it very hard to match. If you could give a more specific format it'd be possible to make a regex that'll much more closely match the input.

Comment: So it is a big long file name i'm trying to parse like. CompanyName_ClientName12345_Month_Nov.pdf the 12345 is our internal identifier for that Client and as they know what their name is we need to strip off the CompanyName_ClientName part and add extra data based on the value of the 12345 number.

Comment: This file list is coming from a 3rd party vendor and they are not changing the file name layout.

Comment: So basically i'm trying to make the final product be something like "InternalDataBasedOn12345"_Month_Nov.pdf as my final file name. Once I get that I will then do another process to rename all the files (that part I know how to do).

Comment: I've updated the answer to include a parsing function for your file's syntax. It'll output an `int id`, `string month` and `string fileExtension` for you to work with and rename the file appropriately. I'll add an explain of the regex.

Comment: I'm thinking this is going to work out great for me I appreciate the help. If I didn't care about separating out the month and just wanted Nov.pdf I should just be able to use ^.*\D(\d+)_Month_(.*) correct?

Comment: Or slightly safer, just remove the `)` after the 2nd group and remove the `(` from the 3rd group: `^.*\D(\d+)_Month_([a-zA-Z]+\.\w+)$`. Getting as close to the source of valid data as possible leaves less room for errors and unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Using :

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"\D+(?=(\d+)_Monthly)");
```

is more explicit, the result is in Groups[1].

Comment: That returns me the numbers needed for part of what I need. So how do I get everything before the 12345 and delete it?

Comment: Was able to figure out that extra bit by doing .+?\D+(?=(\d+)_Monthly)

Answer (score 0):

Part by part:

```
.+?
```

Match anything, maybe. This doesn't make any sense to me. It would be equivalent to ".*", which may or may not be what you meant.

```
(?=
```

start a group
    \d
Match exactly 1 decimal, which explains what you are seeing, and the rest of the number is matched by .+? which is outside the group

```
_Monthly
```

match the literal text

```
)
```

end group

I think what you want is:

```
.*(?=\d+_Monthly)
```

Comment: Your example here on J8T12345_Monthly returns J8T1234.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing the + sign after \d

```
.+?(?=\d+_Monthly)
```

This should ask for one or more digits.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need anything before the number, this should work:
`(\d+_Month)`
I use Derek Slager's regex tester when I'm working with C# regex.

[Better dotnet regular expression tester](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx)

Comment: Basically I need everything before the 12345_Month in order to remove it from the text. So your suggestion above returns me the 12345_Month but how do I get everything before that? My regex skills are lacking.

Comment: Slager's regex is down.  Here's an alternate https://dotnetonlinetools.com/A-Better-Dotnet-Regular-Expression-Tester